# Pycharm не выводит в консоль результат работы программы

Tags: python

[image]

Непосредственно сам код [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То что выводится после запуска программы
Я только начинающая, так что не судите строго((

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)